# Child component not updating when parent state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following child component:

```
    class Adjust extends Component {
        render() {
        const { values, toggleSelector, SELECTOR } = this.props;
        console.log("values are", values"); //this is only being entered once right now
        
        return(
        <div
        key={values}
        style={{
          marginBottom: "25px",
          width: "80vw",
        }}>
         <button
                buttonSelected={values[index]?.add}
                onClick={() => {
                  toggleSelector(index, SELECTOR.ADD);
                }}
          >
         "Add"
        </button>
       </div>
      )}}
```

And this is how I pass props to this child

```
<Adjust  values={values} SELECTOR={SELECTOR} toggleSelector={this.toggleSelector}> </Adjust>
```

I have a console log in my `toggleSelector` function in my parent component, which shows that it is being entered, but even though the state is changing, the render of `Adjust` component is not being entered again.

I have tried adding a key to it but that didn't help.

This is the `toggleSelector` function

```
      toggleSelector(index, selector) {
        console.log("enter");
        let { values } = this.state;
        values[index][selector] = true;
        if (selector === SELECTOR.ADD) {
          values[index].subtract = false;
        } else if (selector === SELECTOR.SUBTRACT) {
          values[index].add = false;
        } 
        this.setState({
          values,
        });  

}
```

This was all working fine when Adjust was not a child component but within the parent. Had to make it a child for better code readability

Comment: First of all here `console.log("values are", values"` one ending parenthesis missing in the above code.

Comment: Sorry, added it

Comment: Still facing an issue or resolved now.

Comment: still facing it

Comment: Can you share the exact code of both of your components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't manage `values` like an immutable variable, `values` is the same array between renders, you only update it's content.

You can find more information there [Correct modification of state arrays in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26254086/4871259)

Comment: But the state is updating, because if I do a `console.log(values)` in the parent component, that is updating

Comment: The state is updating but react consider `values` unchanged and does'nt re-render the child.
Try with `this.setState({values: [...values]})` and read the linked answer.

Comment: Hello, I'm also facing another issue that the child component is rendering, but the changes are shown by one click delay. So for example, if I click on something it changes after I click on something else.

Comment: Could this be also because of the problem in your answer? I'm now updating `values` based on this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/45878231/14683403

Comment: The child doesn't render immediatly after click on button ? did you change the parent / child component ?